# ASP.Net url rewrite from ...pdf to ...aspx (IIS 7)

Tags: asp.net, rewrite

I am trying to rewrite a url for a pdf to an aspx page it isn't working.
I doesen't see the request in my iis-log either.

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="PDF" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="PDF/(.*?)/(\d*)/(.*?.pdf)$" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="SISPdf.aspx?id={R:2}&amp;fn={R:1}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

An example:

```
http://myserver:8089/PDF/ABC/123/DEF_456.pdf
```

should be rewritten to:

```
http://myserver:8089/SISPdf.aspx?id=123&fn=ABC
```

With all my attempts I get HTTP 500 or HTTP 404.

Is it possible to debug rewrite-rules?

**Edit:**

At the old IIS (<= 6) i remember me that i must set the **ISAPI-Filter** for ASP/ASP.Net on PDF or Image file extension so the IIS know that he must handle this. Is there any equivalent?

Comment: Have you verified that .pdf is listed in your IIS mime types?

Comment: no, how i do this?

Comment: btw: static pdf's would be shipped

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
<match url="PDF/(.*?)/(\d*)/(.*?.pdf)$" />
```

to

```
<match url="PDF/(.*)/(\d*)/(.*).pdf$" />
```

Also, take off "stopProcessing='true'". Since you're doing a rewrite, you would actually like to continue processing.

Comment: doesn't work -> 404 - File or directory not found

Comment: I just modified it, give it another shot.

Comment: doesn't work too

Comment: i also try "PDF/(.*)/(\d*)/(.*)\.pdf$" and "^PDF/(.*)/(\d*)/(.*)\.pdf$"

Comment: What error are you getting now?

Comment: Also, try taking off "stopProcessing='true'"

Comment: "404 - File or directory not found"

Comment: At the old IIS (<= 6) i remember me that i must set the ISAPI-Filter for ASP/ASP.Net on PDF or Image file extension so the IIS know that he must handle this. Is there any equivalent?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6056/discussion-between-floyd-and-mike-richards)

Answer (score 0):

To debug the URL Rewrite module, you can use the IIS 7.x "Failed Request Tracing," which, contrary to its name, can be used to trace successful as well as failed requests. This [learn.iis.net page](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules) illustrates how to configure this and amount of detailed debugging information that is available.  You don't need to create a test page as suggested in the blog entry--- just jump to the "Configure Failed Request Tracing" section.